# Intuition behind PCA decorrelation and whitening

Tags: pca

1) Is there an intuitive explanation for why data becomes correlated once rotated into the principal component basis?

2) Is there any intuitive explanation behind why rotation doesn't affect the whitening of data?

Specifically, I want to understand why $x_{ZCA} = U x_{PCA}$ where $x_{PCA} = D^{-1/2} U$ for the eigen decomposition of $X X^T$ works.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't what you mean.

2)  The definition of whitening is that $E(XX^T)$ is the identity where $X$ is a vector-valued random variable.  Any rotation by $U$ of that $X$ will also be whitened since, by definition, the transpose of a rotation vector is its inverse.

Comment: 1) I mean, when I do $x_{pca} = U^T \ x$, how does this make $x$ decorrelated?

Comment: @learning https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00809 is an accessible source.